# Photon PUN 2 | Teleport bug when master changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, photon-pun

I need some help with photon. I have a fast PhotonView object and its master is constantly changing. Sometimes this object is teleported on other devices. Do you know the solution? how can i create a solution

I tried using RPC and the result was still the same.

```
 using UnityEngine;
   using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
public class CustomTransformView : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IPunObservable
{
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        Application.targetFrameRate = 45;
        PhotonNetwork.SendRate = 30;
        PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate = 25;
    }
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(rigidbody.position);
            stream.SendNext(rigidbody.rotation);
            stream.SendNext(rigidbody.velocity);
        }
        else
        {
            // Bu oyuncu veri alıyor
            Vector3 targetPosition = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            Quaternion targetRotation = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
            Vector3 targetVelocity = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();

            float lag = Mathf.Abs((float)(PhotonNetwork.Time - info.timestamp));
            float lerpTime = lag * 50f; // Geçiş zamanlamasını ayarlayın


            print(lag);
            if (BallManager.Instance.UserId == "")
            {
                lerpTime = 25 * lag; // Geçiş zamanlamasını ayarlayın
            }
            else
            {
                lerpTime = lag * 50; // Geçiş zamanlamasını ayarlayın
            }

            // Rigidbody bileşenlerinin konum, rotasyon ve hızını pürüzsüz bir şekilde güncelleyin
            rigidbody.position = Vector3.Lerp(rigidbody.position, targetPosition, lerpTime);
            rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rigidbody.rotation, targetRotation, lerpTime);
            rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rigidbody.velocity, targetVelocity, lerpTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.